# Hiding Full Column In Crystal Report Using Formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I want when my `PickUpsCRY` is greater than 0,this column is fully disappear else it should be shown .[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: _squint_ Is that a crosstab? Also, do you mean when the **SUM** of the PickUpsCRY column is greater than 0?

Comment: No it is normal report.i mean when any value in PickUpsCRY is > 0,PickUpsCRY columns disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really suppress horizontal space in the same way you can suppress vertical space (via the suppression of report sections, etc.). So, while you could technically suppress that column's fields, header, lines, etc. with the suppression formula `max({table.PicksUpsCRY})>0`, you won't be able to get rid of the whitespace and it'll appear as though you've just got a hole in your table.

You could move this column to the end so it's not as obvious that there is a column missing, though.