# Crystal Report Column Hiding Completly

Tags: crystal-reports

My output is currently as follows

```
**Name**                         **Age**                 **Hobbies**
  Micheal                          20                            Football
  Jimmy                            23                            Hockey
```

I want when Age is greater than 20 ,age column disppear and output looks like as follow

```
**Name**                           **Hobbies**
    Micheal                                Football
    Jimmy                                  Hockey
```

Thanks.Kindly tell me how to do this using **crystal syntax**

Comment: What happens if you have a mix of ages (> 20 and <= 20)?

Comment: You should edit your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513305/hiding-full-column-in-crystal-report-using-formula) rather than creating a new one.